# Are ">>"s in type parameters tokenized using a special rule?

Tags: java, parsing, token

I'm confused by the [Java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) about how this code should be tokenized:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> i;
```

The spec says:

> The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.

As I understand it, applying the "longest match" rule would result in the tokens:

- ArrayList
- <
- ArrayList
- <
- Integer
- >>
- i
- ;

which would not parse.  But of course this code is parsed just fine.

What is the correct specification for this case?

Does it mean that a correct lexer must be context-free?  It doesn't seem possible with a [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) lexer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623966/java-syntax-of/2624125#comment2646754_2624125

Comment: I assume you meant `i` instead of `1` in your list of tokens.

Comment: Maybe you can submit a bug.

Comment: @johnchen902 is it a bug?  I hadn't considered that possibility.  I don't really think it is, though.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Maybe bug in documentation. You can tell how are generics parsed from the following code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/javac/parser/JavacParser.java#JavacParser.typeArguments%28boolean%29

Comment: @smartus I see, their approach makes sense.  Do you mind if I write that up as an answer or would you prefer to do it?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to write the answer properly. I understand the code and I remember a few things about grammars from Uni, but I'd prefer a person who actually understands the whole picture to write the answer. You do it ;)

Comment: it has been a well known problem in C++ - http://stackoverflow.com/a/71706/2158288 no doubt the language designers are very aware of this problem, but they don't seem to be concerned enough to bring it up in the spec.

Comment: At the beginning of generic type parameters in java, one had to insert a space in `> >`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on reading [the code linked by @sm4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/javac/parser/JavacParser.java#JavacParser.typeArguments%28boolean%29), it looks like the strategy is:

- tokenize the input normally.  So `A<B<C>> i;` would be tokenized as `A, <, B, <, C, >>, i, ;` -- 8 tokens, not 9.
- during hierarchical parsing, when working on parsing generics and a `>` is needed, if the next token starts with `>` -- `>>`, `>>>`, `>=`, `>>=`, or `>>>=` -- just knock the `>` off and push a shortened token back onto the token stream.  Example:  when the parser gets to `>>, i, ;` while working on the typeArguments rule, it successfully parses typeArguments, and the remaining token stream is now the slightly different `>, i, ;`, since the first `>` of `>>` was pulled off to match typeArguments.

So although tokenization does happen normally, some re-tokenization occurs in the hierarchical parsing phase, if necessary.

Comment: Why compiler don't re-tokenize things such as `a--b`?

Comment: @johnchen902 why should it?  Retokenization isn't a general strategy for rescuing failed parses, it's only used in one special case so that you don't have to write `A<B<C>  >`.

Answer (score 1):

Java 10 Language Specification (3.2 Lexical Translations) states:

*The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would. There is one exception: if lexical translation occurs in a type context (§4.11) and the input stream has two or more consecutive > characters that are followed by a non-> character, then each > character must be translated to the token for the numerical comparison operator >.

The input characters **a--b** are tokenized (§3.5) as **a, --, b**, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization **a, -, -, b** could be part of a grammatically correct program.

Without the rule for > characters, two consecutive > brackets in a type such as `List<List<String>>` would be tokenized as the signed right shift operator >>, while three consecutive > brackets in a type such as `List<List<List<String>>>` would be tokenized as the unsigned right shift operator >>>. Worse, the tokenization of four or more consecutive > brackets in a type such as `List<List<List<List<String>>>>` would be ambiguous, as various combinations of >, >>, and >>> tokens could represent the >>>> characters.*

The earlier versions of C++ too apparently suffered from this and hence required at least one blank space between the two adjacent less than(<) and greater than(>) symbols like `vector <vector<int> >`. Fortunately, not any more.